# In a swap transaction with raydium do I need to pass the amountIn?

Tags: solana-program

I currently have a script that swaps SOL for a specific token, and then from that specific token back to SOL. It turns out that I don't know how much I received in the first swap (SOL -> token) until the transaction is confirmed. Is there any way to infer the amount received in the first swap transaction? So as not to depend on her confirmation and be able to send the second one (token -> SOL).

Answer (score 1):

If the token swaps are part of two separate transactions, then no there is not. You would have to wait for the first to confirm and then send the second.

You could alter your code to perform both swaps in the same transactions by listing multiple token swap instructions in the single transaction. This is the way that the second swap would "depend on" the first.

Since the instructions within a solana transaction are executed atomically, each would execute in order and should a previous instruction fail, the entire transaction would fail.

You would need to make sure you account for the token balanced being enough for the transaction to ensure all the swap instruction success. i.e. if the first swap results in 5 tokens remaining, and the second sway needs 6 tokens to pass, then the entire transaction would fail

PS: This is basically how Jupiter swap works

Comment: In this case, both legs of the SWAP would go in the same transaction, right? I need them to go in separate transactions, one after the other. I want to reduce the time between one and another (currently I'm depending on the first confirmation, to know what the amount received was).

Comment: why do they need to be in multiple transactions?

Comment: It is a snipping operation of pre-released tokens. Here's an example:

Transaction 1: https://solscan.io/tx/2ZX7aV2SJ2UvHRerH8cUHhuqRcXHmH5B8MK8YyZThP83n4tcW76qaP6RNXaCm5ZU7Y2DLiiXpsxbvQJk8MNxoTmb

Transaction 2: https://solscan.io/tx/4tVb11eTfza8uRg8oQwbDP5krdtpk8ZF3ASqevwgNGpwBNxHz6S5JFY3WtfVA6eoRkuPevfmJXPUDEDkczirPshH

Comment: Understood. Yeah, I am fairly certain you would have to wait for the first one to confirm. I suppose you could also have your code track some state and give a best guest attempt. Running multiple transactions (off the same wallet) in parallel and perform each. But I think you would open a lot of risk on the arb